# If the series 1/n diverges so does 1/3n, 2/n and so on?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can I multiply or divide the series' general term and still maintain its nature?

Comment: not any number $\neq 0 $ but any number $>1$ I guess...

Comment: So 1/3n still diverges?

Comment: Yes @user2810177. See Did's answer below: you can multiply by any non-zero constant $c$, and the series will still diverge.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $c\ne0$. The series $\sum\limits_nx_n$ diverges if and only if the series $\sum\limits_ncx_n$ diverges.

Comment: Thank you, this made it clear.

Comment: Short and sweet! +1